# how to filter gridview by DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi all I have a gridview and some data in it ,but I want to filter by date
I have startTime and EndTime which are thesame, ideally I would like user to click on say 04/05/2015 items for that day shows up ,but I have been struggling with it now can get it to suit my purpose, find below is my Datetimepicker method Please note I am using an access DB to retrieve data.,what are my doing wrong thanks in advance?

```
string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE StartTime >= #{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm}# AND EndTime <=#{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm}#", dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy hh:mm"));
```

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out perhaps, but dates should always be handled like dates, not strings. So:

```
string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE StartTime >= #{0:yyyy'/'MM'/'dd}# AND EndTime <#{1:yyyy'/'MM'/'dd}#", dt, dt.AddDate(1));
```

and:

```
string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CompletedIngredients WHERE DateScanned >= #{0}# AND DateScanned < #{1}#", dt.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd"), dt.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd"));
```

Comment: You are spot on !! @Gustave much respect :))

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my self ,all I needed was just to take out completely **"hh:mm:ss"**
**This is my new solution and for future some else can benefit :))**

```
string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM CompletedIngredients WHERE DateScanned like #{0}#", dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy"));
```